# JavaMailSenderImpl sending inline photos

Tags: spring, jakarta-mail, velocity

I'm trying to send an email using Spring's mail implementation, and using velocity templates for replacing content of html files. So far it has worked great, but right now I'm facing trouble when trying to add a second inline image to the mail is gonna to be sent.

My velocity template is this one:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ndeveloper publishing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header" style="background-color: #eeeeee">
        <div align="center">
            <p><em>Header1</em></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="paragraph1">
            <img src='cid:${photo1}' width="200px" height="200px" style="display: block;float: left; margin: 0em 1em 1em 0em "/>
            <p>${paragraph1}
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="paragraph2>
            <img src='cid:${photo2}' width="200px" height="200px" style="display: block;float: right; margin: 0em 0em 1em 1em "/>
            <p>${paragraph2}
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"  style="background-color: #eeeeee">
        <div align="center">
            <p><em>Footer1</em></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now the code that I'm using to send the mail looks like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void sendTemplateMail(VelocityMailMessage message) {
    Connection connection = null;
    Session session = null;


    try {
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        Velocity.init(initializeVelocityProperties());
        VelocityContext velocityContext = new VelocityContext();

        HashMap<String, Object> parameterMap=message.getReplaceableParameters();
        HashMap<String, Attachment> attachmentMap=message.getAttachList();

        //${paragraph1} and ${paragraph2} are replaced here
         for (String key : parameterMap.keySet()) {
            velocityContext.put(key, parameterMap.get(key));
        }
        //Here the inline photos identifiers should be replaced ${photo1} and ${photo2}
        int k=1;
        for (String key: attachmentMap.keySet())
        {
            //INLINE_PHOTO_PREFIX has a value of "photo"               
            velocityContext.put(Constants.INLINE_PHOTO_PREFIX+k, attachmentMap.get(key).getIdentifier());
            k++;
        }

        StringWriter text = new StringWriter();
        Velocity.mergeTemplate(message.getTemplateName(), "UTF-8", velocityContext, text);

        List<String> emailList = message.getTo();

        ArrayList<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Iterator<String> iterator = emailList.iterator(); iterator
                .hasNext();) {
            String[] tmp = null;
            String[] tmp1 = null;
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            String name = (String) iterator.next();
            tmp = name.split(";");
            while (i < tmp.length) {
                tmp1 = tmp[i].split(",");
                i++;
                j = 0;
                while (j < tmp1.length) {
                    emails.add(tmp1[j]);
                    j++;
                }
            }

        }
        if (!emails.isEmpty()) {
            emailList = emails;
        }

        JavaMailSenderImpl sender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = sender.createMimeMessage();
        String[] toArray = new String[emailList.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (String to : emailList) {
            toArray[i] = to;
            i++;
        }


            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);

            helper.setText(text.toString(), true);
            helper.setTo(toArray);
            helper.setFrom(message.getFrom(), "Portal");
            helper.setReplyTo(message.getFrom());
            helper.setSubject(message.getSubject());
            if (message.getAttachList() != null) {
                if (!(message.getAttachList().isEmpty())) {
                    Set<String> keys = message.getAttachList().keySet();
                    for (String string : keys) {
                            Attachment at=message.getAttachList().get(string);
                            if(at.isInline()){
                                helper.addInline(at.getIdentifier(), at.getAttachFile());
                            }else{
                                helper.addAttachment(string, message.getAttachList()
                                .get(string).getAttachFile());
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            sender.setHost(parameterServiceLocal.parameterByName("SMTP HOST")
                    .getValue());
             sender.setUsername(parameterServiceLocal.parameterByName("SMTP USER").getValue());
             sender.setPassword(parameterServiceLocal.parameterByName("SMTP PASSWORD").getValue());
            Properties p = new Properties();

            p.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
            p.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            sender.setJavaMailProperties(p);
            sender.send(mimeMessage);

    } catch (VelocityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.getMessage(); 
    }
    catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (session != null && session != null) {
            try {
                session.close();
                connection.close();
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Where `Constants.INLINE_PHOTO_PREFIX` is simple the string "photo" used to replace the values in the vecloity template.

The problem is that when you check the mail sent to your inbox, it only shows the first photo where the ${photo1} symbol is. I already checked and all the parameters reaching

```
if(at.isInline()){
          helper.addInline(at.getIdentifier(), at.getAttachFile());
}
```

are correct, even the velocity template is modified correctly. SO what would be a possible reason for this to fail?. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That code is hard to read. You need to break it up into smaller methods so that we can make sense of it. Start by separating the velocity stuff from the mail stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, thanks for the advice. Found the problem later.... it was just this part

```
<div id="paragraph2>
        <img src='cid:${photo2}' width="200px" height="200px" style="display: block;float: right; margin: 0em 0em 1em 1em "/>
        <p>${paragraph2}
```

Since I never closed the quotes the image was never displayed. My fault, really sorry and thanks again for the response.